# create a Rest API with customized header request

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, http-headers

I'm falling into a problem this morning with a custom request between two application, what I need to do is to let application able to talk each other with two Rest API cause I need to do some actions on the first application by the second. The two applications are developed with springboot.

Suppose to call this two applications **admin** and **superadmin**

superadmin send a request with a RestAPI and a customized header -> name = key value = 1234

admin recieve the request and first of all check if the header is present or not, after that the header is finded it can proceed to do all the task.

Here's the code that i've developed :

SUPERADMIN :

```
    @PostMapping(value="/test_api_header")
    public ResponseEntity<String> test_API(@RequestParam String url) {
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        URI targetUrl = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url) // Build the base link
                .path("/test_API") // Add path
                .build() // Build the URL
                .encode() // Encode any URI items that need to be encoded
                .toUri(); // Convert to URI
        MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.add("superadminKey", "123456abc");
//      build the request
        ResponseEntity<String> entity = template.exchange(targetUrl, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<String>(headers), String.class);
        return entity;
    }
```

ADMIN :

```
    @Value("123456abc")
    private String saKey;

    @GetMapping(value = "/superadmin/test_API")
    public String test_API(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (request.getHeader("superadminKey") == saKey) {
            return "Finally";
        } else {
            return "Nothing to do, header not present";
        }
    }
```

The SUPERADMIN is able to communicate with the RESTApi in the ADMIN application, in fact on postman I received the answer : Nothing to do, header not present, but i really cannot be able to set that customized header in the superadmin request cause I cannot found it also on postman request in the section "headers".

I've seen that I could also create a customized API Key for this special case, but really don't know how it works, if someone could help me I would be very grateful!

Comment: Add reading of request headers public String test_API(@RequestHeader MultiValueMap<String, String> headers, HttpServletRequest request) {}

Comment: thank's man! it function, now i can handle the headers key in the application ;)